# Program accepting input but does not give output

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
  clrscr();
  int a,b,c;
  printf("enter the 2 numbers: ");
  scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
  c=a+b;
  printf("the sum is : %d ",c);
  return(0);  
}
```

this is a simple program to add 2 numbers.
my program would let me input the value..but it would not print the sum ,nor would it print the next line.
it would run till the scanf() and as i press enter, it would jst exit the program.
can you please tell me whats wrong. I am a beginner programmer...

Comment: are you sure it doesn't print the sum and then exit the program?

Comment: By "exit the program" do you mean the whole window closes?

Comment: end lines \r\n are missing

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you should think of here.

End printouts with a newline character, because stdout is often line buffered. Do `printf("the sum is : %d \n",c);` instead. Or call `fflush(stdout);` expliticly after the printout. This will ensure everything gets printed.

Add some input code in the end. Like an extra `scanf("%d", &a);` This is basically a small hack to prevent the window from closing before you can see the final output. Another alternative is to add `sleep(3);` to sleep for 3 seconds. A third alternative here is to see if there are some settings that controls the closing of the window in your IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Your program works correctly, but it exits right after printing the output, giving you no time to look at it.

Consider adding some input before `return(0);`, such as 2 `getchar();` calls. You need 2, because the first character read will be the `\n` that you typed after the numbers.